# How to get Swagger to send api_key in Header and in request URL?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am able to either get the API key to be represented as a header or as a tag on the end of the URL, but I am needing it to be both. Is there any way for this to be possible? The picture is linked
[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add(swashbuckleConfig.apiKeyName, new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization(swashbuckleConfig.apiKeyName, key, "header"));
      window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add(swashbuckleConfig.apiKeyName + " query", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization(swashbuckleConfig.apiKeyName, key, "query"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Define both the header and the query parameter in the `securityDefinitions` section (in OpenAPI 2.0) or the `components/securitySchemes` section (in OpenAPI 3.0) of your API definition:

```yaml
# swagger: '2.0'

securityDefinitions:
  apiKeyHeader:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-EGEN-AccessTokenID
  apiKeyQueryParam:
    type: apiKey
    in: query
    name: api_key   # replace with your query param name
```

Then, if you need **both** the header and query param be passed in the same request:

```yaml
security:
  - apiKeyHeader: []
    apiKeyQueryParam: []
```

Or if **either** the header or query param should be used, but not both:

```yaml
security:
  - apiKeyHeader: []
  - apiKeyQueryParam: []
```

More info here:
http://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

In Swagger UI, when you click "Authorize", you will be enter the values for both the header and the query parameter.

Comment: Could you please help me with this , not able to add apiKey as query param in swagger 3.x i.e. latest version ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050969/setting-swagger-apikey-in-version-2-0?noredirect=1#comment85145482_49050969

Comment: Thanks for this, worked for me with `openapi: '3.0.0'`